# Parsing "stringified" JSON in scala/play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm implementing a Scala/Play API (apiA) which consumes an API (apiB) that I have no control over. ApiB returns a JSON response which in some cases has JSON embedded into strings. Example:

```
{
  "name":"some_name",
  "scores": "[[10,15]]",
  "data": "{\"attr1\":\"value1\",\"attr2\":\"value3\"}"
}
```

ApiA needs to access the value of `name` before passing all the data along to the client and it should be provided to the client as proper JSON.
I'm considering parsing the raw response into a

```scala
case class Response(name: String, scores: JsValue, data: JsValue)
```

or

```scala
case class Response(name: String, scores: Seq[Seq[Int]], data: Map[String, String])
```

For now it doesn't really matter what type `scores` and `data` are parsed into as long as it's not a string containing JSON.

Now, if the JSON response was well formed writing format/reads/writes would be straightforward but I'm sort of breaking my head on how to got about converting the content into JSON before parsing into the final types.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```scala
case class Response(name: String, scores: Seq[Seq[Int]], data: Map[String, String])

import play.api.libs.json._

val stringified = Reads[JsValue] {
  _.validate[String].flatMap { raw =>
    try {
      JsSuccess(Json.parse(raw))
    } catch {
      case cause =>
        JsError(cause.getMessage)
    }
  }
}

implicit val respReads = Reads[Response] { js =>
  for {
    name <- (js \ "name").validate[String]
    scores <- (js \ "scores").validate(
      stringified).flatMap(_.validate[Seq[Seq[Int]]])
    data <- (js \ "data").validate(
      stringified).flatMap(_.validate[Map[String, String]])
  } yield Response(name, scores, data)
}

Json.parse("""{
  "name":"some_name",
  "scores": "[[10,15]]",
  "data": "{\"attr1\":\"value1\",\"attr2\":\"value3\"}"
}""").validate[Response]
// JsSuccess(Response(some_name,Vector(Vector(10, 15)),Map(attr1 -> value1, attr2 -> value3)),)
```